# Laravel 4 Hybridauth Server not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mamp, hybridauth

I've installed the hybridauth package into my laravel 4.2.* setup. I'm running MAMP.

I'm using the code of app/config/hybridauth.php and app/routes.php from this example:

https://github.com/vohof/laravel-hybridauth

When I open the url `http://localhost/auth/facebook/` in Mozilla, this leads to a 'Server not found' page in Mozilla Firefox and the url changes from `http://localhost/auth/facebook` to `http://www.localhost.com/auth/facebook`

in Safari there's no url-redirect but a white page is displayed. These problems only appear with Laravel 4.2.* BUT NOT with Laravel 4.0.0. In Laravel 4.0.0 I get a proper redirect to the twitter page.

Does anyone have a clue why this is and where this problem comes from?

Any help appreciated,
Roman

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `.htaccess` file in the public directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```